# How can I get my input in a txt file, after the program runned

Tags: python-3.x

How can i make a textfile from the input off the user?

```
f = open('test.txt','w')

    date = input("which day is it")

print("" + date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `write()` function.

```
date = input("which day is it")

with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(date)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it helped my code. have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("text.txt","a") as txt_file:
    txt_file.write(input("What is your name?\n"))
```